# SOAP for Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, soap, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

can anyone guide me how to build a SOAP service and hosting it in a server and calling back it in to a windows phone application

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241261.aspx) can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources on MSDN about consuming Web Services (and REST Services as well) on Windows Phone. You can find some of them here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487167%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958%28VS.95%29.aspx

http://hadyelsahar.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/webservices-in-wp7/

And a complete video tutorial at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241261.aspx

Hope, these links will help.

Mayur Tendulkar